# How to make a template overwrite for mod_menu with alternative layouts for link outputs?

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla3.1

I understand and love template overwrites.  I need to do some heavier changes to the menu output (basically making the output work better with Bootstrap) - but only for certain menus.

Currently in Joomla 3 there are the following in the `mod_menu/tmpl` folder:

```
default.php
default_component.php
default_heading.php
default_separator.php
default_url.php
```

If I want to change the classes I'd copy the default.php into my `mytemplate/html/mod_menu` and change it.  Great, no problem.

If I want to change the link outputs to go along with that I can copy the default_component.php to `mytemplate/html/mod_menu` and change it.  Great, no problem.

If I want to have the choice of having a different "Alternative  Layout" I'd rename the `mytemplate/html/mod_menu/default.php` to `newlayout.php`, then select it in the admin module manager for that menu.  Great, no problem.

Here's the problem:  If I want to have the link output changed for certain menus but not all of them I figure I'd change `default_component.php` to `newlayout_component.php` like I did above which would correspond to the `newlayout.php`...but that doesn't work.

Questions:

1)  How to have alternative layouts for each of the `default_component.php`, `default_heading.php`, `default_separator.php`, `default_url.php` template files (not just an overwrite)?

2)  I would think `default_url.php` is the one that would affect the link outputs but it seems it's `default_component.php` that does.  So what does each one of those do?  I couldn't find any information on joomla.org about that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The alternative layout feature only works for the main file (`default.php`), not for the sublayouts (`default_component.php`, ...). So you have to create your own `newlayout.php` which then can load `newlayout_component.php`, or use the `default_component.php`. In fact, the `default_component.php` will be used as fallback if no newlayout_component.php is found.
2. The code switches over the `$item->type` of the link. `'separator'`, `'url'`, `'component'` and `'heading'` are handled by the `'default_'.$item->type`, everything else will use `default_url`. So a plain URL should indeed be generated by `default_url.php`, not `default_component.php`. If it behaves differently, it's likely a bug.